# how to parametrize python sorting

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I have the following code in python for sorting

```
cursor.execute('SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 from Table1');
Details = cursor.fetchall()

def mixed_order(Details):
    return (Details.Column1,
            Details.Column2,
            Details.Column3
            )

Sorted_Details = sorted(Details,key=mixed_order)
```

I want to parameterize the mixed_order function by saying

```
Criteria1 ="Details.Column2"
Criteria2 ="Details.Column1"
Criteria3 ="Details.Column3"
```

and define the following

```
def mixed_order(Details):
    return (Criteria1,
            Criteria2,
            Criteria3 
            )
```

But, python is not sorting my details. Something is wrong in the way I defined the Criteria's and assign the columns to it.

Comment: What's wrong? Which error are you getting? What's the unwanted behavior?

Comment: @Korem: The code is running, but sorting is not happening. The same order is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
def mixed_order(Details):
    return (getattr(Details, Criteria1),
            getattr(Details, Criteria2),
            getattr(Details, Criteria3)
            )
```

Comment: Thanks @Knio, it worked                                                Critirea1 = str("Column1")                                                                                                                          def mixed_order(Details):
    return (getattr(Details,Critirea1))